# Preventing interface from becoming default route

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualization, interface

I'm kind of a linux noob and have been messing with this a night and a day now, so I thought I'd ask here.

I have a FreeNAS and a Ubuntu 18.04 VM running under a ESXi host. The FreeNAS VM has a HBA passed through with my disks, and manages the pool and shares. The Ubuntu VM will be doing my automation, NextCloud and Plex.

Both VM's have interfaces linked to my home network, but they also both have a second interface that is attached to a Storage Network in ESXi. (As described here: https://b3n.org/freenas-corral-on-vmware/. Although I don't use the storage linked up to ESXi for extra VM's) I created the extra network so that the traffic between both VM's doesn't have to go through my gateway but has a full interface at it's disposal for just file traffic.

The issue I'm running into is that both the interfaces in the Ubuntu VM, so both the interface to WAN and the storage interface, receive a default route configuration. But the second one has no WAN link obviously, so when it tries to route traffic over that, everything just fails.

What can I do to prevent that or how else should I configure it?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't set a gateway IP on the storage only network.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. Feels a bit dumb but oh well, I'm learning.

Comment: It happens, no worries.  I converted the comment to an answer so you can accept it and mark this question resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set a gateway IP for the storage network interface.

The adding of a gateway adds a route of a default route over that gateway.  If you don't set the gateway, the only route added is the route for that specific IP subnet to its own range and nothing else.

That will prevent the system trying to go out to other resources over that storage subnet that has no uplink beyond its own subnet.